# Can you select all exists in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have been building an access manager to police API interactions in my application.  I have a model which represents a User having Access to a given model instance, it looks like:

```
class Permission(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

The access manager is aware of model hierarchies and can figure out that if you're trying to view or modify a given object type with a given ID, that it can check if you have permissions on it, or on a parent entity in the tree.  It builds up Q objects, and hits the database asking if a relevant permission exists for the user.

I have come to a new use case, where a particular entity has 2 parents in the tree, and I need the access manager to check that the user has permissions somewhere one **both** sides of the tree.

Here is a (sanitised) Q object that I thought is what I needed:

```
<Q: 
(AND: 
    (OR: 
        (AND: ('content_type', <ContentType: myapp | foo>), ('object_id', 676)), 
        (AND: ('content_type', <ContentType: myapp | bar>), ('object_id', 634)), 
        (AND: ('content_type', <ContentType: myapp | wibble>), ('object_id', 1))

    ), (OR: 
        (AND: ('content_type', <ContentType: myapp | foo>), ('object_id', 2)), 
        (AND: ('content_type', <ContentType: myapp | bar>), ('object_id', 633)), 
        (AND: ('content_type', <ContentType: myapp | wibble>), ('object_id', 2))
    )
)
>
```

Assume that a Foo is a parent to a Bar (a Bar has an FK to Foo), and a Bar is a parent to a Wibble (Wibble FK to Bar). So in words, what I'm trying to do with this, is to check:

1. The user has access to ANY of:

   - Foo with id 676
   - Bar with id 634
   - Wibble with id 1
2. AND that the user ALSO has access to ANY of:

   - Foo with id 2
   - Bar with id 633
   - Wibble with id 2

i.e. does the user have access to both of the Wibbles, or any parents of both Wibbles.

Here is the current data in the relevant DB table

```
SELECT * FROM myapp_permission;
  id  | object_id | content_type_id | user_id
------+-----------+-----------------+---------
 1181 |       676 |              30 | 316740
 1182 |       633 |              29 | 316740
```

So (just believe me on the ContentType IDs) the user does have access to Foo with ID 676 and a Bar with ID 633, so the user does have permissions on both sides.  But the above Q object when applied like:

```
Permission.objects.filter(the_q_object).exists()
```

... returns False.  I have figured out this is because the query is asking for a SINGLE row that fulfils both criteria, instead of 2 (or more) rows that *combine* fulfil it.

So after all that context, the question is: how can I modify the Q object to perform the query I'm after?

Comment: Can you do something like Permission.objects.filter(Q(first_side_of_tree) | Q(other_side_of_tree)).exists() This way the outermost AND in your Q representation becomes an OR.

Comment: But that would require permissions only on one side of the tree.  I require that the user has perms on both.

Comment: My bad I misunderstood your question. What about starting from `User` and doing something like:  `User.objects.filter(id=request.user.id).filter(permissions__in=Permission.objects.filter(first_side_of_tree)).filter(permissions__in=Permission.objects.filter(other_side_of_tree)).exists()`

Comment: For reasons hard to go into (essentially the AccessManager is already over 300 lines of pretty complex code, that all hinges on building queries for, and querying the Permission model) a rewrite like that is not easy :(

Comment: I have thought about just doing 2 queries, something like `if Permission.objects.filter(first_tree).exists() and Permission.objects.filter(second_tree).exists(): return True else: return False`, but given this is used on every API request, I'm desperately trying to keep DB hits to a minimum

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries I think this is the best way to go.